# Paypal Button Error - AMOUNT_ERROR - Multi-Options

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, paypal, webflow

Hello I am a developer who is new to developing for **PayPal**, and I've been handed a legacy *application/website* that has been running successfully for several years. Unfortunately, the person who was responsible for developing this website was not a strong believer in the value of documentation or future-proofing. I have had to make several major leaps of faith on the logic between sections of this **ASP.NET MVC** application and its calls to its supporting database.

But more to the point, the website has been utilizing **PayPal** buttons and its **IPN** functionality to communicate with a database for years. In those cases, we've only ever had a single product, associated with a single button ID. However, in the last month I've been asked to start supporting options as well so that users can select if they want certain things along with the product to modify their 'end price'.

The old section of the website that was serialized and submitted via jquery/javascript looked like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="@Drawn from Database and Model@">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="orderNumber" value="">
</form>
```

The changes that I've made were based on a new test button I created on the company's account which had the following fragment:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Item (Y/N)">Item (Y/N)</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="os0">
    <option value="No">No $1.00 CAD</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes $1.20 CAD</option>
    </select> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I added the following to the previous section to try to support that.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="@Drawn from Database and Model@">
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Yes">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="orderNumber" value="">
</form>
```

However, upon testing and attempting to retrieve the product that I'm 'buying' **Paypal** gives me a screen that says

**"Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."**

With a URL that ends with code=AMOUNT_ERROR

As I said , these forms appear to be submitted in `javascript/Jquery`, and more specifically in a **webflow.js** document, using `submit()`.

Anybody have a guess as to why I'm receiving this error? Perhaps I should be rearranging the format of the form more substantially to be in line with the structure of the example button? Or maybe I should use os0 as a name for the item in the form instead of on0? I would contact PayPal support directly, but that is quite difficult to do, given that I don't own the account that I am supporting, and the person who does own it is hard to get on hand for a substantial stretch of time.

**Edit:** Sorry guys, I found it. It was the name of value I serialized that was wrong. Paypal couldn't figure it out. What I should have named that field was **os0** and not **on0**.

Comment: Please add a working code and Where is your amount order input inside your form method?

Comment: The amount is on the PayPal side of things, as there are some inconsistencies between the amounts displayed on the website and that which PayPal calculates with taxes. And what do you mean by 'working code'? I only have fragments of the webflow.js to share, and it would help to know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this guys, but I'm going to have to answer my own question this time. I was trying to serialize and post 'on0' to PayPal at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr previously. My mistake was that PayPal doesn't understand that, despite how you could use it to trigger button options using raw URL queries. My correction became the following:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="@Drawn from Database and Model@">
    <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="Yes">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="orderNumber" value="">
</form>
```

I know this question didn't make too much sense. I'm just glad I figured out the solution before my supervisor emphasized his demand for this functionality. I guess in IT we all have to make our deals with legacy code, and ham-handed workarounds by temporary employees. Sorry about that.